# how to get version details out of an API

Tags: c#, xml, api

basically im trying to show that the connection to the API has been successful by showing the version.
my code is

```
Console.WriteLine("Connecting to the IntuVision API");
            string APIversion = "http://10.0.1.****/info";
            Console.WriteLine(APIversion);
```

and it just prints the actual URL rather than the details i need
im unsure how to go about this as im new to using APIs

Comment: what details?? your code snippet is just printing static string

Comment: all i need is the version details, the manual for the api says that that url ending in /info is all i need to get these details

Comment: Are you sure the api even supports the `/info` method?

Comment: @Neil according to the user guide i was sent it does

Comment: yes, but your are literally just outputting (writing) the url to console. You aren't executing anything, you aren't navigating to the url, there is nothing in your code that would return any result besides console output.

Comment: Why is this labeled XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at something like: https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/

The example is pretty clear.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            var result = await client.GetAsync("http://10.0.1.****/info");
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }
```

(I presume in your example **** is actually a number?  There is no need to obfuscate internal IP addresses (10.X.X.X, 172.16.X.X, 192.168.X.X) as they are not reachable from the external internet.)

Comment: this worked, thank you :0